# how can i get my submit button to hide and then show only when all the information is filled?

Tags: html, input, submit

I want to make a website and my submit button to create a new account is showing and whenever clicked is moving on to the next page.
I want the submit button to show only when the person has already filled in all the information.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="submit" id="mySubmit">

<p>Click the "Try it" button to disable the Submit button.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled = true;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```